# How can I create a gif with more than 256 colors like this one?

Tags: photoshop, gif, 256color

Bonjour ! this is my first question !

I'm trying some UI animation in Photoshop, and I want to export in GIF file. But, GIF can't support more than 256 colors right ? So my quality is really low...

I think I found a gif with 32697 colors on this website, so is it possible ?...

http://phil.ipal.org/tc.html

If someone can explain me how it's work... I'm pretty lost.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Wikipedia has [some discussion of how this can be done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#True_color). It sounds like it's quite a complex format to create (compared to a "normal" GIF with a single palette), so possibly not many tools support it.

Comment: Ok so I can't create this with PS or with an other soft ?

Comment: This site is specifically aimed at programmers; you might find [a sister site](http://stackexchange.com) which is more suited for how to do create such an image with a tool, rather than writing your own.

Comment: Also see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/39904/7654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True-color GIFs are a hack that uses the animated GIF format, puts a 256 color square in each frame, offset from all previous frames, makes each frame not disappear when the next frame appears, and loops only once. Few programs other than web browsers display such images correctly. The files are very large as a result and not suitable for web use.

Try PNG instead.

Comment: Yikes, gif frames with a different palette for each frame? That sounds like a dirty hack.